# Selecting a specific row in UITableview

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, selection

I have a Address Book in my app. In that, there is a tableview and a contact details page(refer screenshot). When i add a new contact, the most recently added contact details are displayed in the contact detail page but how to make the recently added contact be selected in the tableview..? Note: the contacts are sorted in alphabetical order in the tableview..

Answer (score 1):

If you are adding your recent array in the end of tableView then

```
if (indexPath.row==[yourContactAry count]-1) {
        [tableView selectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath
                                    animated:NO
                              scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionNone];
    }
```

**OR**

If you are adding any where in tableView then get index of your array then get indexPath then applyCode, like.

```
NSInteger indexOfArry=[yourContactAry indexOfObjectIdenticalTo:yourRecentAddedRecord];
NSIndexPath *indexPath=[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:indexOfArry inSection:section];
```

Comment: cellForRowAtIndexPath

Answer (score 0):

Use `setSelected:(BOOL)selected` method on the cell you want to select.

Answer (score 0):

```
if you are maintaining contacts array then take the topmost item as the reference of your last created contact.
Or else if you are having any index of the contact then take that index and point to the array your contact is stored.
or else if your contact object or address object has the date field compare that with other records and fetch the latest one.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
[self.tableView selectRowAtIndexPath:selectedIndexPath
                                                      animated:NO
                                              scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionNone];


set selectedIndexPath in which you want, if select top most item means,

_selectedIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0];
```